# Compare a file in the device with one in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

My app download html files from the database the first time the app is opened.

When a button is clicked I want to check every html file and download an "updated" html version (Only if the html in the device is different from the one in the database)

How can I do that kind of comparison?

My main activity onCreate with a boolean to check if is the first time the app is opened then a function getFiles() is called to download every html file.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    button_horarios = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_horarios);

    Boolean isrunfirst = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).getBoolean("first", true);

    if(isrunfirst){

        getFiles();
        getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putBoolean("first", false).apply();
    } else {

    }

}
```

getFiles function with a loop used to "loop" through a String array containing the name of the files, with the name the file is retrieved from the database and finally the file is saved using a function saveFile()

```
public void getFiles(){
    FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    final StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReference();

    final String[] grupos = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.array_grupos);

    for(int i = 0; i < 97; i += 1) {

        final int finalI = i;
        StorageReference htmlRef = storageRef.child("grupos/" + grupos[finalI] + ".html");

        final long ONE_MEGABYTE = 1024 * 1024;
        htmlRef.getBytes(ONE_MEGABYTE).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<byte[]>() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(byte[] bytes) {

                saveFile(grupos[finalI] + ".html", bytes);

            }
        }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {

            }
        });
    }

}
```

saveFile() takes the file name and the bytes, the bytes are converted into a string an saved.

```
private void saveFile(String file, byte[] bytes) {

    try {
        String text = new String(bytes, "UTF-8");
        FileOutputStream fis = openFileOutput(file, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fis.write(text.getBytes());
        fis.close();
    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: for starter, you compare the hash of both files...

Comment: And how do I check if a file is missing?

Comment: you do that with `File.exists()` method